# Should Angular Service Execute In Unit Test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angularjs-service

I am trying to integrate Karma and Jasmine in to my project.

I have started off with a very basic test to ensure my controller is defined and a $scope variable equals a string - which pass as expected.

My controller, also calls a service which performed a $http.get, when running my test, without any mention of a service, i get the error:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET /my/endpoint/
No more request expected
```

Controller:

```
define(['module'], function (module) {
    'use strict';

    var MyController = function ($scope, MyService) {

        $scope.testScope = 'karma is working!';

        MyService.getData().then(function (data) {
            $scope.result = data.hour
        });
    };    

    module.exports = ['$scope', 'MyService', MyController ];
});
```

Test:

```
define(['require', 'angular-mocks'], function (require) {
    'use strict';

    var angular = require('angular');

    describe("<- MyController Spec ->", function () {    

        var controller, scope;

        beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

        beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {
            scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
            controller = _$controller_('MyController', {$scope: scope});  
            scope.$apply();
        }));

        it('should verify that the controller exists ', function() {
            expect(controller).toBeDefined();
        });    

        it('should have testScope scope equaling *karma is working*', function() {
            expect(scope.testScope ).toEqual('karma is working!');
        });
    });
});
```

Are the above errors expected?

---

UPDATE from response below:

```
define(['require', 'angular-mocks'], function (require) {
    'use strict';

    var angular = require('angular');

    describe("<- MyController Spec ->", function () {    

        var controller, scope, $httpBackend, myService;

        beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myApp'));

        beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_, _myService_) {
            scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            $httpBackend.expectGET("/my/endpoint");
            controller = _$controller_('MyController', {$scope: scope});  
            scope.$apply();
        }));

        it('should verify that the controller exists ', function() {
            expect(controller).toBeDefined();
        });    

        it('should have testScope scope equaling *karma is working*', function() {
            expect(scope.testScope ).toEqual('karma is working!');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes: Your test creates an instance of your controller. Your controller calls your service when instanciated. The service sends an HTTP request when called. And you haven't cofigured the $httpBackend to respond to such a request. So the request is indeed unexpected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Angular Mocks you will always get an error if there is an unexpected or incorrect http request attempted -- even for templates. In your case there are two ways to handle this for testing:

#### use `$httpBackend`

[`$httpBackend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) was designed for testing http requests without actually hitting the wire. In your test, simply add

```
$httpBackend.expectGET("/my/endpoint");
```

before you initialize the controller.

#### Mock the service

The service itself is making the http request, so you can mock the service instead. Services will be injected automatically as usual, but you can explicitly injection whatever you want:

```
controller = _$controller_('MyController', {$scope: scope,
MyService: {getData: () => ({then: () => {}}) });
```

This injects an object that has a `getData` function which returns an object with `.then` function. Of course this doesn't come close to implementing what you are trying to do, but it is another way to perform the test.

Both of the above approaches are valid. It depends on what you are testing and what you are trying to accomplish with the testing.

Comment: thanks for such a detailed answer, i followed your advice and added the above above my controller and got the error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$httpBackend.expectGET')

Comment: see update above. I get error  Error: No response defined !

Comment: Ok, fixed it, need .respond([{}, {}, {}]); at the end of ("/my/endpoint")